# What is the difference between lasso and WOE encoding in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, mathematical-statistics, lasso

I know lasso is one of the best method to select important variables and make variables sparse. But WOE encoding does the same thing, making variable smooth.

1. I would like to know what is the difference between lasso and WOE in result of logistic model?
2. If I have used WOE encoding, when I train the logistic model, can I use lasso?

Comment: Lasso is a penalisation method, i.e. changing the objective function of the model fitting step to get different coefficient in the fitted model. WOE is a variable transformation method that smooth the variables.

Comment: What's the meaning of somoothing the variables?Can you explain it?